How to Troubleshoot Select2 Dark Theme Issues on Bootstrap 5
select2 problem
i am having a problem on select2 when the switch to dark mode on bootstrap 5 select2 input does not change to dark mode
I use Mazer templates
i want when switch to dark mode select2 input also change to dark mode

If you are using select2-bootstrap-5-theme you need to change color from fixed (e.g.: #212529) to dynamic (e.g.: var(--bs-body-bg)):
body .select2-container--bootstrap-5 .select2-selection {
    color: var(--bs-body-color);
    background-color: var(--bs-body-bg);
    border: var(--bs-border-width) solid var(--bs-border-color);
}

body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5.select2-container--focus
    .select2-selection,
body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5.select2-container--open
    .select2-selection {
    border-color: var(--bs-link-hover-color);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(13, 110, 253, 0.25);
}

body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5
    .select2-selection--multiple
    .select2-selection__clear,
body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5
    .select2-selection--single
    .select2-selection__clear {
    background: transparent
        url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23676a6d'%3e%3cpath d='M.293.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L8 6.586 14.293.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L9.414 8l6.293 6.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L8 9.414l-6.293 6.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L6.586 8 .293 1.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e")
        50%/0.75rem auto no-repeat;
}
body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5
    .select2-selection--multiple
    .select2-selection__clear:hover,
body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5
    .select2-selection--single
    .select2-selection__clear:hover {
    background: transparent
        url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23000'%3e%3cpath d='M.293.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L8 6.586 14.293.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L9.414 8l6.293 6.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L8 9.414l-6.293 6.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L6.586 8 .293 1.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e")
        50%/0.75rem auto no-repeat;
}
body .select2-container--bootstrap-5 .select2-dropdown {
    color: var(--bs-body-color);
    background-color: var(--bs-body-bg);
    border-color: var(--bs-link-hover-color);
}

body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5
    .select2-dropdown
    .select2-search
    .select2-search__field {
    color: var(--bs-body-color);
    background-color: var(--bs-body-bg);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: var(--bs-border-width) solid var(--bs-border-color);
}
body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5
    .select2-dropdown
    .select2-search
    .select2-search__field:focus {
    border-color: var(--bs-link-hover-color);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(13, 110, 253, 0.25);
}
body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5
    .select2-dropdown
    .select2-results__options
    .select2-results__option.select2-results__message {
    color: #6c757d;
}
body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5
    .select2-dropdown
    .select2-results__options
    .select2-results__option.select2-results__option--highlighted {
    color: var(--bs-body-color);
    background-color: var(--bs-light-bg-subtle) !important;
}
body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5
    .select2-dropdown
    .select2-results__options
    .select2-results__option.select2-results__option--selected,
body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5
    .select2-dropdown
    .select2-results__options
    .select2-results__option[aria-selected="true"]:not(
        .select2-results__option--highlighted
    ) {
    color: var(--bs-body-color);
    background-color: var(--bs-dark-bg-subtle);
}
body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5
    .select2-dropdown
    .select2-results__options
    .select2-results__option.select2-results__option--disabled,
body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5
    .select2-dropdown
    .select2-results__options
    .select2-results__option[aria-disabled="true"] {
    color: #6c757d;
}
body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5
    .select2-dropdown
    .select2-results__options
    .select2-results__option[role="group"]
    .select2-results__group {
    color: #6c757d;
}
body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5
    .select2-selection--single
    .select2-selection__rendered {
    color: var(--bs-body-color);
}
body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5
    .select2-selection--single
    .select2-selection__rendered
    .select2-selection__placeholder {
    color: #6c757d;
}
body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5
    .select2-selection--multiple
    .select2-selection__rendered
    .select2-selection__choice {
    color: var(--bs-body-color);
    border: var(--bs-border-width) solid var(--bs-border-color);
}

body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5.select2-container--disabled
    .select2-selection,
body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5.select2-container--disabled.select2-container--focus
    .select2-selection {
    color: #6c757d;
    background-color: var(--bs-light-bg-subtle);
    border-color: var(--bs-dark-bg-subtle);
}
.is-valid + body .select2-container--bootstrap-5 .select2-selection,
.was-validated
    select:valid
    + body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5
    .select2-selection {
    border-color: #198754;
}
.is-valid
    + body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5.select2-container--focus
    .select2-selection,
.is-valid
    + body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5.select2-container--open
    .select2-selection,
.was-validated
    select:valid
    + body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5.select2-container--focus
    .select2-selection,
.was-validated
    select:valid
    + body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5.select2-container--open
    .select2-selection {
    border-color: #198754;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(25, 135, 84, 0.25);
}
.is-invalid + body .select2-container--bootstrap-5 .select2-selection,
.was-validated
    select:invalid
    + body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5
    .select2-selection {
    border-color: #dc3545;
}
.is-invalid
    + body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5.select2-container--focus
    .select2-selection,
.is-invalid
    + body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5.select2-container--open
    .select2-selection,
.was-validated
    select:invalid
    + body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5.select2-container--focus
    .select2-selection,
.was-validated
    select:invalid
    + body
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5.select2-container--open
    .select2-selection {
    border-color: #dc3545;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.25);
}

